# Issues creating a high pressure chamber for corrosive solution

Tags: design, pressure, chemical-engineering, experimental-physics, seals

I'm trying to do an experiment on high pressure's effect on the electrical impedance of a really corrosive solution. I'm aiming for at least 2,000 psi with a pressure chamber but the only material I found that's chemically inert is PTFE and it's really limiting. One of my design is to use a PTFE diaphragm at the opening of the tube and press it inside the chamber to create pressure, and the other one is to push a PTFE piston into a tube directly but I don't know if it will hold much pressure.

The problem is that I can't really find a pre-made diaphragm that's under $500 that suits my chamber. Also, I can't find a way to fit a pressure gauge into the chamber and seal it properly. If you have an idea where to find these parts or any suggestions on how I should improve my design to better accommodate these challenges, that would be a great help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

High Pressure corrosion testing is usually done in alloys like  Hastelloy C ( or similar). Autoclave Engineers corp makes a lot of this equipment. Of course in this area it is usually done on a "money is no factor" basis.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you have any suggestions on the design and how the pressure can be measured?

Comment: For pressure above 2000 psig , I think Swageloc is the most recommended tubing fittings , flare and other compression fittings are not as reliable. A regular gauge with a Hastelloy bourdon tube could work , but then you have your solution in that tube , so I don't know the best long term pressure measurement.